# How to limit MySQL query for specified column values

Tags: mysql

Let's say i have a table :

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+-------------+
| cust_id | fed_id      | cust_type_cd | address               | city       | state | postal_code |
+---------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+-------------+
|       1 | 111-11-1111 | I            | 47 Mockingbird Ln     | Lynnfield  | MA    | 01940       |
|       2 | 222-22-2222 | I            | 372 Clearwater Blvd   | Woburn     | MA    | 01801       |
|       3 | 333-33-3333 | I            | 18 Jessup Rd          | Quincy     | MA    | 02169       |
|       4 | 444-44-4444 | I            | 12 Buchanan Ln        | Waltham    | MA    | 02451       |
|       5 | 555-55-5555 | I            | 2341 Main St          | Salem      | NH    | 03079       |
|       6 | 666-66-6666 | I            | 12 Blaylock Ln        | Waltham    | MA    | 02451       |
|       7 | 777-77-7777 | I            | 29 Admiral Ln         | Wilmington | MA    | 01887       |
|       8 | 888-88-8888 | I            | 472 Freedom Rd        | Salem      | NH    | 03079       |
|       9 | 999-99-9999 | I            | 29 Maple St           | Newton     | MA    | 02458       |
|      10 | 04-1111111  | B            | 7 Industrial Way      | Salem      | NH    | 03079       |
|      11 | 04-2222222  | B            | 287A Corporate Ave    | Wilmington | MA    | 01887       |
|      12 | 04-3333333  | B            | 789 Main St           | Salem      | NH    | 03079       |
|      13 | 04-4444444  | B            | 4772 Presidential Way | Quincy     | MA    | 02169       |
+---------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+-------------+
```

And I want to write a query which returns rows with MA state limited to max 5 and NG state limited to max 2. How can I write multiple limit statements in one query?

Comment: You want the first five based on cust_id or some other order?

Comment: Please share more details. What's the expected output for the given input data, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your select statement

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY cust_id) as RN
```

and the following to the WHERE

```
 WHERE (state = 'MA' AND RN <= 5) OR (state = 'NG' AND RN <=2)
```

you will need to move the where to an outer select on a sub query